Create an assistant and continue to use the thread until the user stop the conversation
I'm doing same experiment with ChatGPT and I found the NuGet called OpenAI-DotNet that seems quite easy to use. What I like to have is a conversation between the user and the AI. I understood that the Assistant is the right way to implement it. So, I wrote this code:
var request = new CreateAssistantRequest(Model.GPT4o);
assistant = await client.AssistantsEndpoint.CreateAssistantAsync(
    new CreateAssistantRequest(
        name: "English Teacher",
        instructions: "You are a personal English Teacher.",
        model: Model.GPT4o));

var messages = new List<Message> { "Good morning! How is the weather?" };
var threadRequest = new CreateThreadRequest(messages);

chats = await assistant.CreateThreadAndRunAsync(threadRequest);

What I can't find is how to add more messages to continue the chat after creating a thread. Only in messages, I can add more messages. That means I have to recreate every time I add a message a new chats?

I do not want to be "that guy" but this sounds like a "RTFineM" ? There seems to exist an exhaustive documentation. Even with a "cookbook" ...  Nothing in there helped? Why?

@Enrico I made a YouTube tutorial on this. Feel free to check it out. Also, my GitHub repo might help you.
